# VS Code Go: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the Go features of VS Code (like 'Go to definition') in a package with a `go.mod`. However, if I go into the repository's main directory (with the go.mod) and `code .`, I get this error:

[image]

> Error loading workspace folders (expected 1, got 0) failed to load view for file:///Users/kurt/Documents/http-enrollment-portal: err: exit status 1: stderr: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

I've read that I might have to update the `gopls` language server, so I pressed Cmd + Shift + P and selected "Go: Install/Update Tools" and selected `gopls`; however, this gives me the same error:

```
go.toolsGopath setting is not set. Using GOPATH /Users/kurt/Documents/http-enrollment-portal:/Users/kurt/go
Installing 1 tool at /Users/kurt/Documents/http-enrollment-portal/bin in module mode.
  gopls

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls FAILED

1 tools failed to install.

gopls:
Error: Command failed: /usr/local/opt/go@1.12/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls
$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
```

The strange thing is that 'Go to definition' does work in other repositories. I suppose a possible solution is to set the `go.toolsGopath`?

Comment: Is the error incorrect? Does `/Users/kurt/Documents/http-enrollment-portal/go.mod` exist? (or `/Users/kurt/go/go.mod`?)

Comment: For me, it happens a lot. Restarting VSCode normally fixes it.

Comment: Yes, the `go.mod` does exist...

Answer (score 2):

```
  go env -w GOPATH=
```

#### GOPATH and Modules

[this link](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable)

When using modules, GOPATH is no longer used for resolving imports. However, it is still used to store downloaded source code (in GOPATH/pkg/mod) and compiled commands (in GOPATH/bin).

Comment: I've struggled on a fresh install using the official golang installer, this comment helped me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. So to explain I am using https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup
To try Mongodb with Go. In VS Code I first installed `go mod init quickstart`
Then I used `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` and got the error `$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not`.
I had previously set my GOPATH according to https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setting-up-go-programming-language-on-windows-f02c8c14e2f/ (see Phase 3 on this page).
I went into my Windows Environment Variables and deleted my GOPATH. On the Windows 10 start menu go to `System` then `Advanced system settings` under the `Advanced` tab click the `Environment Variables` button and I deleted my `GOPATH` variable.
Next back in VS Code I again try `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to the folder where you created your go project and delete the go.mod file after you create another file with the command : go mod init nameproject  on your command prompt (power